# How do I get gapi loading in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have been trying to create a basic event using the google calendar API, firebase, and react but I keep getting the error that gapi is not loading. This is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ApiCalendar from 'react-google-calendar-api';
import { apiCalendar } from "../../firebase/calendar";
import { useState } from "react";
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';
import { confirmPasswordReset } from "firebase/auth";

export const LandingPageButtons = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const testCalendarApi = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("Clicked");
            await apiCalendar.createEventFromNow({
                time: 50,
                summary: 'summary',
                description: 'description'
            });

            console.log("Event created successfully!");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error creating event:", error);
        }
    };

    // Define the gapiLoaded function
    const gapiLoaded = () => {
        console.log("Gapi loaded from script tag");
        console.log("token", gapi.auth.getToken());
    };

    // Attach the gapiLoaded function to the onload property of the script element
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js";
        script.onload = gapiLoaded;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
v
        // Cleanup: remove the script when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, []); // The empty dependency array ensures that this effect runs only once

    return (
        <div className='bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-400 via-blue-300 to-blue-200 h-screen w-screen flex justify-center'>
            <div className='w-4/5 sm:w-4/6 md:w-1/2 mx-auto'>
                {/* Rest of your component */}
                <div className='text-center h-30 mt-5 '>
                    <button
                        disabled={loading}
                        onClick={testCalendarApi}
                        className='bg-blue-900 text-white border-none rounded-lg cursor-pointer text-base w-4/5 h-16 sm:w-4/5 sm:h-14 md:text-lg md:w-6/12 transform transition-transform hover:scale-95 active:scale-100 hover:shadow-none shadow-lg'
                    >
                        Test Calendar API
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I tried following react-google-calendar-api documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-calendar-api) to make a button that creates an event upon being hit, and right now my console shows that the event is being clicked + created, but because gapi is not loading no event is actually being made. Does anyone know what the problem may be? Thanks in advance!